# css selector for shadow-root(closed), python 3

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, scrapy, css-selectors

I want to extract next page url from the following html using css selector for scrapy spider.

```
<button id="omni-next-click" name="searchnextclick" class="btn btn__blue btn__rounded" aria-label="next" data-reactid="971" omnivalue="1">
 <span class="icon icon__arrow-right" data-reactid="972">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" data-reactid="973">
   <use xlink:href="/images/adaptive/livestyleguide/walgreens.com/v3.0/themes/images/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon__arrow-right" data-reactid="974">
    #shadow-root (closed)
     <svg id="icon__arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
       <title>icon__arrow-right</title>
       <path d="M13.312 21.952c-0.144 0-0.288-0.064-0.4-0.176-0.224-0.224-0.224-0.592 0-0.816l4.976-4.976-4.976-4.96c-0.224-0.224-0.224-0.592 0-0.816s0.592-0.224 0.816 0l5.376 5.376c0.224 0.224 0.224 0.592 0 0.816l-5.376 5.376c-0.128 0.112-0.272 0.176-0.416 0.176z">
       </path>
     </svg>
   </use>
  </svg>
 </span>
</button>
```

I am new to scraping. Please help me through it. How can I find css so that I can crawl through all the available pages?

Comment: `#icon__arrow-right`?

Comment: yes, I want to have the hyperlink so that I van go to the next page.

Comment: To select element with link: `#omni-next-click use[xlink\:href]`

Comment: gives me the following output  ```<use xlink:href="/images/adaptive/livestyleguide/walgreens.com/v3.0/themes/images/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon__arrow-right" data-reactid="974"></use>``` also I think this is a url to image and not the next page.

Comment: What’s the next page URL in that HTML fragment? Is it even there? The original website seems to be using React, so maybe you should start by reading https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html